# Boolean algebra in computer science

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

The problem is here.
I don't have enough reputation to post the picture so here is the Imgur link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zpwg.jpg

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: how do you solve this type of question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simplify the question by turning each condition to a variable.

so, "(y > 10000) || (x > 1000 && x < 1500)"

becomes (a) || (b && c)

Use the distributive property...

(a || b) && (a || c)

Which makes the answer...

"(y > 10000 || x > 1000) && (y > 10000 || x < 1500)"

Which is Option "B".

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.